# Currency exchange

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the land of Jyok, there are three units of currency: the Blok, the Clok, and the Dlok.
You are told that 2 Bloks and 5 Cloks is worth 52 Dloks, while 3 Bloks and 4 Cloks is
worth 57 Dloks. How much is 4 Bloks and 3 Cloks worth? My answer is 58 Dlocks. Am I correct?

Comment: Are we buying or selling?

Comment: It can help if you show your work. It helps people guess what kind of explanation might be suitable. If you made a mistake, someone may then be able to say exactly where you went astray, which I find more useful than “You’re wrong!” when I have made a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is incorrect. Start by defining

$$\text{B=Blok},\quad\text{C=Clok},\quad\text{D=Dlok},$$

and write out both equations:

$$2B+5C=52D\tag{1},$$
$$3B+4C=57D\tag{2}.$$

We want to form $4B+3C$, so we can multiply equation $(2)$ by $2$ to get:
$$6B+8C=114D. \tag{3}$$

Then $(3)-(1)$ forms:

$$4B+3C=62D.\tag{4}$$

Therefore, $4$ Bloks plus $3$ Cloks equals $62$ Dloks!

Answer (score 0):

N0, you're wrong. Try to see the problem as two sets of equations!

Take the second equation:

$$3B + 4C = 57D$$

Multiply it by $2$ getting

$$6B + 8C = 114D$$

Now subtract the first equation ($2B + 5C = 52D$) from this one to get

$$4B + 3C = 62D$$

Hence the answer.

Comment: Thanks all so much. I will definitely show my work next time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, isn't that cute! (I hate "cute"!)

Abbreviating "Blok" as "B", "Clok" as "C", and "Dlok" as "D",

"2 Bloks and 5 Cloks is worth 52 Dloks" so 2B+ 5C= 52D.
"3 Bloks and 4 Cloks is worth 57 Dloks"so 3B+ 4C= 57D.

"How much is 4 Bloks and 3 Cloks worth?"

By subtracting the first equation from the second, B- C= 5D.
Multiplying that by 4, 4B- 4C= 20D.

But we want 4B+ 3C.  We need to add 7C to that.  It would be a good idea to find the value of  C!  Multiplying 2B+ 5C= 52D by 3, 6B+ 15C= 156D. Multiplying 3B+ 4C= 57D by 2, 6B+ 8C= 114D.  Subtracting the first of those from the second eliminates B leaving 7C= 42D so C= 6D.

So 4B+ 3C= 4B- 4C+ 7C= 20D+ 42D= 62D.

Comment: It might have been simpler just to solve the two  equations,  2B+ 5C= 52D and 3B+ 4C= 57D, for C and D.  We can solve for C= 6D as before.  Then 2B+ 5C= 2B+ 30D= 52D.  2B= 52D- 30D= 22D, B= 11D.  Then 4B+ 3C= 4(11D)+ 3(6D)=  44D+ 18D= 62D as before.